# Working with DOS .COM files

Tags: tools, windows, dos-com

What can I do to reverse engineer a DOS .COM file? As far as debugging goes, I've looked DEBUG and DEBUGX from the creators of FreeDOS, as well as the default DEBUG command that comes with Windows. Sure, I can probably work with them and eventually figure out what I'm doing, but I feel like the process would end up being longer than necessary. Is there a better tool I can use?

If there are no "better" tools than DEBUG or DEBUGX, then what can I use to work with output from these two tools? My main goal is to create something that mimics the .COM program, but in a more manageable format (as far as code goes).

Comment: suggested by broadway: [d86](http://www.eji.com/a86/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally use [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com) debugger, which is quite complete, with a SoftICE-like interface.

Otherwise you can go for DOS debuggers like Turbo Debugger or CodeView.

Comment: Cool, I'll try all of them out. I'll get back to you with a response on what worked best for me. So far CodeView looks very promising

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to [Ange's answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1855/245) I would like to offer [idados](https://github.com/wjp/idados). I've had good experiences with it when trying to reverse engineer a program and the accompanying file format. It *also* makes use of [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/). But if you have a proper IDA Pro license it is - I think - slightly more convenient.

Comment: Hmmm... I might look into that when I have the money to get an IDA Pro license. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JMcAfreak: it is why I have added this last sentence. I *think* the SDK wasn't included the last time in the IDA Freeware version and plugins were also (not full or not at all?) supported. But since I have the full version I don't check it too often.

Comment: IDA free doesn't support SDK afaik - there was an unofficial patch for that, which I haven't tested.

Comment: I wish I could select two accepted answers! :P Both seem like really good options. Currently I'm using the stuff suggested by @Ange (I'm trying each one out), but I'll definitely look into this!

Comment: accept @0xC0000022L's then, since it enhances mine (I haven't tried idados personally)

Comment: @Ange: let's leave to the OP's discretion which to choose. Either one is perfectly fine and it's well possible in future someone comes along and had an even better answer and will receive more upvotes than either of us :)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a little late; newcomer to this site. The Decompiler project was initiated in order to decompile MS-DOS EXE and COM binaries. The project has both a command-line and a GUI tool:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/decompiler/

Use the following command with the command-line tool to decompile COM programs:

```
decompile --default-to ms-dos-com myprog.com
```

In the GUI, use the menu command `File` > `Open as...` to open the COM file and specify a start address like 0800:0100.