# Decompilation techniques for DOS .COM files

Tags: tools, decompilation, decompiler, dos-com

I've found a binary copy of a DOS freeware game I was fond of back in the day ([Firefighter](http://dosgamer.com/firefighter/), downloadable as `FIRE.COM`) but the source code is not available. I'd like to re-implement it in C or Python using Unix curses and while I'm fully competent to do that part, I know almost nothing about tools for reverse-engineering and decompiling DOS .COM file binaries.

Going by documentation that says .COM is headerless raw machine code, I tried running `objdump -D -b binary -m i386` on it. The result didn’t look valid. `objdump -D -b binary -m i8086 –adjust-vma=0×100` appeared to do the trick as did using NASM with `ndisasm -b 16 -a -o 0×100` and both of those do seem to produce plausible *assembly* listings.

Ideally, though, I'm looking for something that decompiles and renders to C in *as-if-it-were-assembler* style with generated variable names and useful annotations on the DOS traps. I understand that such a beast may not exist, but on the chance one does I'm seeking recommendations.

Comment: Welcome to RE! Have you searched and looked at the existing questions on the site?

Comment: How is this not in scope under "tools commonly used for reverse engineering hardware or software"?

Comment: [Have you looked through the existing questions?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1854/189) Have you tried out any of the solutions already provided? Where/Why have the existing questions failed? This question shows absolutely no previous research.

Comment: I have updated the question; Can the on hold status be removed?

Comment: Maybe you can get some hints here http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/MachineCodeDecompilers

Comment: According to this answer to a similar question (http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3075/4113) there are *NO* good DOS decompiler available ;(

Comment: Have you tried loading it in IDA? I think you get the traps/system calls annotated which will help. Obviously not a full decompilation but as grkvit said there probably isn't any - I certainly have never heard of one.

Comment: There's no decompiler, but the DosBox debugger is pretty good and can help you gain an understanding. And of course you might just be able to write your own decompiler in the process. Make sure to present it here in an answer to your own question.

Comment: It seems like a relatively simple game. I think decompiling it is an unnecessary step. If you just want to re-implement it, why not write it again from scratch? With the graphic libraries available for Python it shouldn't take more than a weekend.

Comment: @sarkiroka he should have used (7 years ago) IDA Pro 5 Freeware - way way better than ndisasm

Answer (score 7):

My answer is a little late; newcomer to this site. The Decompiler project was initiated in order to decompile MS-DOS EXE and COM binaries. The project has both a command-line and a GUI tool:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/decompiler/

Use the following command with the command-line tool to decompile COM programs:

```
decompile --default-to ms-dos-com myprog.com
```

In the GUI, use the menu command `File` > `Open as...` to open the COM file and specify a start address like 0800:0100.

Answer (score 5):

IDA Pro and a number of other disassemblers will disassemble your file, assuming that it isn't compressed or otherwise obfuscated.  But this is only the first step in producing a working assembly language program, which you will need if you are to translate it into a higher language.

Essentially you are looking at two projects.  The first is to produce a working assembly language version of your game.  The second is to translate the game mechanics and logic into C++ or whatever.  The first is easier than the second.

Answer (score 4):

I recently found a DOS program which turns .COM and .EXE into a simple "pseudo-code".
The program is   ---   exe2c.zip

http://www.codeforge.com/dlpre/201558/cb2e19437871.zip__.html

Not an "excellent" tool, but i found it useful.
Start by executing    ENVMNU.EXE    and then entering the .COM or .EXE filename.
---(hint?)  If better results are necessary, use the individual modules
( such as the DOS to ASM module ) and hand-edit ASM discrepancies 
then feed them to the ASM to C module and observe the results.

-- William Gallant

Answer (score 2):

no beast exist that will decompile 16 bit com program
if you prefer to debug it look for grdb from ladsoft
also have in hand a copy of ralf browns interrupt list for all the
int 21 / int 10 SetCursor / GetCursor calls

also make sure you rename the downloaded exe to be 8dot3 compatible
(name less than 8 charecters)

```
GRDB.EXE firefi.com    

Get Real Debugger Version 9.6  Copyright (c) 1997-2009 David Lindauer (LADSoft)
GRDB comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, for details type `?g'
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `?gr' for details

DPMI Start code hooked
History enabled
eax:00000000 ebx:00000000 ecx:00007500 edx:00000000 esi:00000000 edi:00000000
ebp:00000000 esp:0000FFEE eip:00000100 flag:00000202 NV UP EI PL NZ NA PO NC
ds:1F25 es:1F25 fs:1F25 gs:1F25 ss:1F25 cs:1F25
1F25:0100 E9 25 27       jmp          2828
Size: 00007500
->
```

Answer (score 2):

As I review your application (Fire.COM), I think you should use some DOS debugger like Turbo Debugger 5.0 to debug and reverse this application because I have some encrypted stage in it. If you want to "decompile" these application to C code, it's very hard, I had tried some tools in the past (2008) but there was not a good tool to do it. I also got a C source but there was many inline assembly in it.

Answer (score 1):

For `.com` (MS DOS) programs I use ndisasm (Netwide Disassembler) as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4404700/851957) answer. It is very simple, just work without any magic.